# Opportunity Owner being notified through email on inserting opportunities

Tags: opportunity, account, account-teams

When I am creating a new Opportunity with one of my user's as owner of it, they were getting one email per new Opportunity creation being their Owner.

The email looks like this:

> Chirag Verma to Ashish Garg 
>  
>   You have just created an opportunity on an Account but you are not listed in salesforce as a member of the Account Team. If you will need to quote on this Account, please go to the Account record (using the link below) and select "Request Account Team Change" to get added to the Account Team.
>   Opportunity test         /001e000000B80hsAAB

The problem is if I am creating 50 Opportunities with Owner as one of my user(that is not belonging to related Account Owner or Account Team Member of Opportunity), then he will be getting 50 emails as highlighted above and this is quite annoying.

Can anyone tell me how to stop these email alerts being send to User's.

Thanks & Regards,
Chirag

Comment: i think you will need booleans to manage .For first creation need a logic to stamp that mail has been sent on parent (Trigger i would prefer as not sure order of execution of workflows ) and add that condition in workflow.also explore if rollup can reduce tasks for trigger

Comment: @MohithKumar, I didn't get you..can you please explain me in more brief.<br/> Thanks

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11397/opportunity-owner-being-notified-through-email-on-inserting-opportunities

Comment: can we join chat above to understand more and also i can explain better what i meant by the comment

Comment: @MohithKumar,
Sure...I am joining the chat now.